# CSS (Font Awesome) - changing icon color on different button state without Javascript

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome

As per the title, I want to know how to change [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icon color with different `button` state.

For example, I have these custom `search` and `clear` buttons as follows.
I am also using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) and the class name `btn` is from Bootstrap.

```
<button class="btn search">Search</button>
<button class="btn clear">Clear</button>
```

and I've embedded the icon to the `search` button with `:before` Psuedo Class

```
.search:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f002";
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: darkorange;
}
```

I want to be able to change the `darkorange` to `white` when the 
button is on `:focus`.

Is there a way to do it with CSS?

This is [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/VsQ3U/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `:active` rather than `:focus`.

```
.search:active:before, .clear:active:before {
    color: white;
}
```

Take a look at the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UYsUm/).